# On Click of UITableCell change detail disclosure arrow to loading indicator, segue when JSON loads

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, uitableview

I have a table view of peoples names and when I click on one of them I am brought to that persons profile. The profile page is then loaded with JSON. I want to be able to click on a table cell in the table view and have the detail disclosure button change to a loading indicator until the JSON on the profile is loaded and segue to the profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some example code that demonstrates this very thing here:
http://github.com/meekapps/MEEKActivityIndicators

The general concept though is:

-Store the index of the "loading" cell. Should be initialized out of range (such as -1) from the start.

-When a user taps a cell, store that index and reload that cell.

-When displaying a cell (cellForRowAtIndexPath) either set the cell accessory to a disclosure indicator or an activity indicator (if it's index matches the stored index of the loading cell.

-Don't forget to reset the accessory when the view disappears.